# UITextField with PickerView: Don't allow editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a UITextField associated with a PickerView (the PickerView is the inputView of the textField)
Il works fine, but I would like to disallow editing in my TextField (not be able to select, copy text, to see the insertion point, ...).
I red here to implement textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange, for the delegate of the uITextField, but it doesn't work...
The method is never called, but the delegate is correctly done, because if I implement textFieldShouldBeginEditing, it is called.
Is there any (simple) way to do what I want?

Comment: That's this answer that doesn't work for me, so I posted again...

Answer (score 0):

give your `UITextField` id and then implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate. Inside those delegate, check the `textField` id, if it matches your desired `textField`, run function to called your picker view and return false in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The following disallows pasting and cutting text unless the result is exactly the result from the picker. For example purposes I'm assuming this is a `UIDatePicker`.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    return string == formatter.stringFromDate(datePickerView.date)
}
```

where formatter is something like

```
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Additionally, if you programmatically set the textfield to a string date, you may want to synchronize the `inputView` picker of the textField with

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if let text = textField.text {
        if let date = formatter.dateFromString(text) {
            datePickerView.setDate(date, animated: true)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```